# How did humans attain the wisdom of vedas, according to mimamsa school of thought?

Tags: vedas, purva-mimamsa

Since mimamsa doesn't believe in God, they would definitely reject "*the divine revelation*" thing.

And they will also reject that the Vedas were composed by humans (rishis) because they believe in authorless vedas.

**How did humans (rishis) attain the wisdom of vedas according to mimamsa school of thought in Hinduism?**

---

<sup>Because we didn't have the wisdom of the Vedas from the start</sup>

Comment: *"Because we didn't have the wisdom of the Vedas from the start"* - citation needed

Comment: they believe sound is eternal. Rishis heard these sound waves. The eternity of the Veda depends on this tenet of the Mímáṃsá that sound is eternal. Jaimini maintains that the vibrations of the air "manifest" the always existing sound.

Comment: @GIRIBLR that argument is wrong scientifically. Because humans can hear 20 Hertz to 20000 hertz. So if they can hear why can't I.